# how to bypass calling of parent class paint method

Tags: java, applet

I am working on applet and my class extends a Third party api class which have it's paint(Graphics g) method. This class extends JComponent and call super.paint(g) from it's paint(Graphics g). Now I want to directly call to the JComponent paint method from my class. Is there any  way to do this. I try below but give errors

```
getParent().getParent().paint(g);
```

Or you can understand this by following

```
ThirdPartyClass extends JComponent{

    public void paint(Graphics g){
     super.paint(g);
     //some work
    }
}

MyClass extends ThirdPartyClass{

   public void paint(Graphics g){
      getParent().getParent().paint(g);  // not working giving exceptions
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getParent()` method doesn't do what you think it does. It has nothing to do with inheritance and super classes. It simply returns the awt container that this component lives in *within the UI*.

For example, if the component lives inside a scroll pane, which lives inside a panel, then calling `getParent().getParent().paint(g);` in the component will invoke the paint method of the panel.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, getParent does not get the *inheritance* parent; it gets the *Component* parent, so what you are trying does not do what you want, even if it did work.

Second of all, I think it's time to rethink your applet design.  If you don't want the behavior of the class you are inheriting from, then why are you inheriting from it?  Why don't you just inherit from Component?  I think there might be all kinds of consequences if you attempt to make your class a subclass of ThirdParty, and then bypass some of ThirdParty's behavior but not all of it.

Comment: Actually base problem in my program is at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800006/how-to-put-label-tooltip-and-zoom-efficiently-on-jcchart

But when I decompile the third party class then find it also have paint method which is calling to it's super paint. and it also do some other efforts at it's end in this paint. so I just want to override this paint in my class such that I can bypass the paint of thirdparty paint

Comment: Well, I guess either you have found a bug in JCChart, or you aren't using the tooltip feature correctly in some fashion.  I don't know, I am not familiar with that library.  But you are not liable to solve the problem by somehow bypassing super.paint in your superclass, it just wouldn't make any sense.